# MongoDB v3.4 initialize new field value based on array's value of each record

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection with the following structure:

```
{
    "_id":NUUID(...),
    "MyArray": [{
        "Name": "...",
        "MyId": "..."
    },
    {...}]
},
{...}
```

My task is to introduce a new field ArrayId which has to contain value from MyId if MyArray.Name is X and contain nothing (empty string) otherwise.

I tried the following:

```
db.getCollection('myCollection').aggregate([
    {$addFields: {"ArrayId": {$cond: {if: {$eq: ["$MyArray.Name", "X"]}, then: "$MyArray.MyId", else: ""}}}},
    {$out: "myCollection_backup"}
])
```

but the resulting collection has empty ArrayId for all records.

Can you please help find the error? Is there an easier way to do this in mongo 3.4?

Comment: I will give you a hint. Use `$filter` to find out your matching array element, and then use it to populate the id. See how to use $filter here. https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/

Comment: How exactly do you use the results of filter? It returns one element of the array, how do I retrieve MyId from it?

Comment: Why do you run an End-of-life version of MongoDB? https://www.mongodb.com/support-policy/lifecycles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
 $addFields: {
  "ArrayId": {
    "$reduce": {
      "input": "$MyArray",
      "initialValue": "",
      "in": {
        $concat: [
          "$$value",
          {
            "$cond": {
              if: {
                $eq: [
                  "$$this.Name",
                  "X"
                ]
              },
              then: "$$this.MyId",
              else: ""
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
}
])
```

Explained:

Use $addFileds/$reduce to $concat the MyArray.MyId into the new variable SArrayId in case MyArray.Name="X"

( This is in case we expect only one of MyArray.Name=X , what is expected to happen in case there is more then 1x MyArray.Name=X ? )

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/m8kCQHcMWii)

Here is version updating only when it finds first Name=X(in case there is more then one Name=X):

[Playground2](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nUsfTv4vta4)